# wkhtmltopdf and pdfkit issues in python

Tags: ubuntu, python

Hello I am developing an web with python Flask in a linux server, in doing so I am trying to use `pdfkit` and `wkhtmltopdf`.

I am using a linux server(ubuntu).

In Putty, after logging into my server, at `root@myname:~#`  I downloaded `pdfkit` using `apt-get`, and downloaded `wkhtmltopdf`. And I go to python by typing `python` on the command. And I am trying to convert a url into a pdf file by typing in python;

```
import pdfkit

pdfkit.from_url('sample url','output.pdf')
```

here I got an error saying:

```
IOError: wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code -6. error:
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display.
```

What went wrong? installing was a problem? or which part?

And also, if it works correctly, where can I find the output file? which directory? I am using `WinSCP` to manage files.

Comment: as stated in the above error, you have no display (graphically speaking). I assume that you're using the command-line only Ubuntu server distro?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue with similar use, it means that you don't have any graphic screen available on your machine.

To solve this try to install `xvfb` and use the package `wkhtmltopdf` on which `pdfkit` is written.

In `wkhtmltopdf` we can select auto selecting available screen by `-a` switch, so that kind of solves problem for me. And you can call `wkhtmltopdf` from subprocess, so that kind of works.

Answer (score 1):

The following steps should work for you:

```
pip install pyvirtualdisplay
```

add to you code:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
...
with Display():
    pdfkit.from_url('sample url','output.pdf')
```